# What is the device used to draw 5-line staff (empty) with a pencil/pen?

Tags: notation, terminology

I remember seeing something like that long ago but can't remember what it was called. It is basically a metal gadget that holds 5 pencils or only pencil led and you can draw by hand your own empty staff.
Anybody know?

Comment: The only ones I've seen use chalk and are used exclusively on a chalk board. When I'm looking to draw a staff, I just print staff paper from the internet.

Comment: I agree, Reina, that's all I've seen. It would be pretty simple to make one for pencils (golf pencils would be best) out of stiff wire and soft wood for a handle.

Comment: Although sound convincer really only asked what it was called… I'd call it a music-staff-drawing-gadget. I doubt it has a real name per se, unless it's a particular brand.

Answer (score 18):

It's called a [rastrum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rastrum).

---

The rastrum came into use in preparing copper-plate engravings for music printing. It was simply a fork that one dragged across the plate to "score" the surface. Rastrum is Latin for rake.

As for constructing such a tool *samizdat* (DIY), I see potential in a paperclip, 5 ballpoint refills, and a pair of chaining pliers. I'll say more as soon as I buy some ballpoint refills.

*Edit:* 
[image: ballpoint paperclip rastrum]

It's easy to make with cheap materials, but it works *poorly*. Paperclips are too flimsy. I either need stronger wire or longer wire. Or perhaps a carved wooden frame.

Comment: I felt especially guilty as it was these votes which gained me the 'moderator tools' priviledge. I had to confess it before I got *in trouble.* :)

Comment: I don't think you should be too embarrassed at this. You answered the question (It's called a "rastrum"), and gave a proper link for reference. It's not your fault that this question called for a short answer. Your answer was actually more correct than the answer by Nix (he gave examples of products, but neither gave the general name for the thing).

Comment: It's sad that a dozen pens is cheaper than a dozen refills. :(

Answer (score 6):

This isn't exactly what you asked for, but similar idea: [noligraph](http://www.noligraph.de/Impressum/Home2/home2.html). You could also buy a 5-line pen nib [like this Brause one](http://www.paperinkarts.com/bmusic.html).

Comment: There's a video of it at http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZUu1bd_qdEk but it's not available in britain :(